# Read from CSV file as dictionary and append it into a list

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I get the data in to my dicts from the input() method and write the dicts in to a one list. Now I want to read from a CSV file the datas row for row as a dictionary and save this dictionaries in to the list.

```
kontaktbuch = []

kontakt = {'Anrede': anrede,'Vorname': vorname_kontakt, 'Nachname': nachname_kontakt, 'Strasse': strasse, 'Hausnummer': hausnummer, 'PLZ': plz, 'Stadt' : stadt, 'Telefon1': telefon1, 'Telefon2': telefon2, 'E-Mail': email}

kontaktbuch.append(kontakt)
```

Now I add this method in to my code:

```
def import_csv():
    with open('list.csv') as csvfile:

       reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,delimiter=",")

       kontaktbuch.append(list(reader))
```

The CSV file content:

```
Anrede,Vorname,Nachname,Strasse,Hausnummer,PLZ,Stadt,Telefon1,Telefon2,E-Mail
213,213,2323,2323,2323,23232,323232,23232,32323,2313
sadsad,sadad,adada,dsadasada,sadadsa,sadsada,sadsad,sadsad,asaas,ds
```

But this code put all of the dictionaries in to one index at the list:

```
[(0, [{'Strasse': '2323', 'Stadt': '323232', 'Nachname': '2323', 'Telefon1': '23232', 'PLZ': '23232', 'Anrede': '213', 'Telefon2': '32323', 'Hausnummer': '2323', 'E-Mail': '2313', 'Vorname': '213'}, {'Strasse': 'dsadasada', 'Stadt': 'sadsad', 'Nachname': 'adada', 'Telefon1': 'sadsad', 'PLZ': 'sadsada', 'Anrede': 'sadsad', 'Telefon2': 'asaas', 'Hausnummer': 'sadadsa', 'E-Mail': 'ds', 'Vorname': 'sadad'}]), (1, [{'Strasse': '2323', 'Stadt': '323232', 'Nachname': '2323', 'Telefon1': '23232', 'PLZ': '23232', 'Anrede': '213', 'Telefon2': '32323', 'Hausnummer': '2323', 'E-Mail': '2313', 'Vorname': '213'}, {'Strasse': 'dsadasada', 'Stadt': 'sadsad', 'Nachname': 'adada', 'Telefon1': 'sadsad', 'PLZ': 'sadsada', 'Anrede': 'sadsad', 'Telefon2': 'asaas', 'Hausnummer': 'sadadsa', 'E-Mail': 'ds', 'Vorname': 'sadad'}])]
```

With which method can I write a dict only to a one index at the list?

Comment: for row in reader: kontaktbuch.append(row) ?

Comment: Use `kontaktbuch.extend(reader)`

Comment: both solutions have brought the correct output. thank you @AntonvBR

Comment: both solutions have brought the correct output. thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full example:

```
import csv
import io

s = u"""Anrede,Vorname,Nachname,Strasse,Hausnummer,PLZ,Stadt,Telefon1,Telefon2,E-Mail
213,213,2323,2323,2323,23232,323232,23232,32323,2313
sadsad,sadad,adada,dsadasada,sadadsa,sadsada,sadsad,sadsad,asaas,ds"""

kontaktbuch = []

reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(s),delimiter=",")

for row in reader:
    kontaktbuch.append(row)

# or
# kontaktbuch.extend(reader) suggested by  juanpa.arrivillaga
```

---

**or** using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = u"""Anrede,Vorname,Nachname,Strasse,Hausnummer,PLZ,Stadt,Telefon1,Telefon2,E-Mail
213,213,2323,2323,2323,23232,323232,23232,32323,2313
sadsad,sadad,adada,dsadasada,sadadsa,sadsada,sadsad,sadsad,asaas,ds"""

kontaktbuch = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s)).to_dict("r")
```

---

kontaktbuch return:

```
[{'Anrede': '213',
  'E-Mail': '2313',
  'Hausnummer': '2323',
  'Nachname': '2323',
  'PLZ': '23232',
  'Stadt': '323232',
  'Strasse': '2323',
  'Telefon1': '23232',
  'Telefon2': '32323',
  'Vorname': '213'},
 {'Anrede': 'sadsad',
  'E-Mail': 'ds',
  'Hausnummer': 'sadadsa',
  'Nachname': 'adada',
  'PLZ': 'sadsada',
  'Stadt': 'sadsad',
  'Strasse': 'dsadasada',
  'Telefon1': 'sadsad',
  'Telefon2': 'asaas',
  'Vorname': 'sadad'}]
```